# Filter output stream to only keep portion of text delimited by specific lines?

Tags: asynchronous, closures, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I've created a simple example for what I'm trying to accomplish. Essentially, I need to run a shell command and capture its output but, only a specific portion of it. Take for example the following bash command:

```sh
> echo "hello\nhello\nstart\nI\nWANT\nTHIS\nTEXT\nend\nhello\n"
hello
hello
start
I
WANT
THIS
TEXT
end
hello
```

My expected common-lisp output would be a `(list "I" "WANT" "THIS" "TEXT")`. I have a semi-working solution but wondering how I can get my **exact** desired output and if there is a more idiomatic way of accomplishing this task.

First, I create a closure to track lines I should be processing:

```lisp
(defun make-pre-processor ()
  (let ((proc-lines nil))
    #'(lambda (str)
        (cond
          ((string= str "start") (setf proc-lines t))
          ((string= str "end") (setf proc-lines nil))
          (proc-lines str)))))
```

Next, I use a let statement to launch my program and then loop through the output stream:

```lisp
(let* ((input (concatenate 'string
                "hello\\n" "hello\\n" "start\\n"
                "I\\n" "WANT\\n" "THIS\\n" "TEXT\\n"
                "end\\n" "hello\\n"))
        (command (concatenate 'string "echo " "\"" input "\""))
        (*proc* (uiop:launch-program command :output :stream))
        (stream (uiop:process-info-output *proc*))
        (take-lines? (make-pre-processor)))
  (uiop:wait-process *proc*)
  (loop while (listen stream) collect
    (funcall take-lines? (read-line stream))))
```

Which returns

```lisp
(NIL NIL T "I" "WANT" "THIS" "TEXT" NIL NIL NIL)
```

As you can see there are `T` and `NIL` values that I do not want. I also have to use `uiop:wait-process` which I don't particularly like, but I'm assuming that is required.

Broader picture, I have about 100 of these commands I need to run and parse. So I will be looking to run this in parallel. That is just for some perspective, I will post that in a separate question.

Comment: Rather than reinventing a small part of awk in Lisp, wouldn't it just be easier to, well, use awk to do the initial filtering, and then use the Lisp program to digest the output of that?

Comment: @tfb I thought about it, but it’s my first lisp project so I wanted to cut my teeth on just about everything I could to test drive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> (loop for e in '(NIL NIL T "I" "WANT" "THIS" "TEXT" NIL NIL NIL)
        when (stringp e)
        collect e)
("I" "WANT" "THIS" "TEXT")
```

Also this:

```
CL-USER 17 > (defun skip-lines-until (stream stop-line)
               (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
                     while (and line
                                (not (string= line stop-line)))))
SKIP-LINES-UNTIL

CL-USER 18 > (defun collect-lines-until (stream stop-line)
               (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
                     while (and line (not (string= line stop-line)))
                     collect line))
COLLECT-LINES-UNTIL

CL-USER 19 > (let ((lines "hi
there
start
1
2
3
stop
more
here"))
               (with-input-from-string (stream lines)
                 (skip-lines-until stream "start")
                 (collect-lines-until stream "stop")))
("1" "2" "3")
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to do all the work in one place, you can use `loop` to encode the state machine:

```
(with-open-file (in "/tmp/example")
  (loop
    for previous = nil then line
    for line = (read-line in nil nil)
    for start = (equal previous "start")
    for end = (equal line "end")
    for active = nil then (and (not end) (or active start))
    while line
    when active collect line))
```

Here is table of what value is bound to each loop variable over the time, where the dot denotes nil for readability.

```
|----------+-------+-------+-------+------+------|
| line     | hello | start | text  | text | end  |
|----------+-------+-------+-------+------+------|
| previous | .     | hello | start | text | text |
| start    | .     | .     | T     | .    | .    |
| end      | .     | .     | .     | .    | T    |
| active   | .     | .     | T     | T    | .    |
|----------+-------+-------+-------+------+------|
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to accomplish this. I think I have to up my loop construct knowledge before I can grasp this completely.